# INDEX MATCH with multiple look ups

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am making a pricing guide and need the cell to match the product, with the respective price.

So if I need 1oz of Four Roses Bourbon, it would first look up "four roses", then find the cost of 1oz.

[image: Image of said file]

Currently my formula looks like this,

```
=INDEX(Spirits!$F$3:$F$200,MATCH($F$3,Spirits!$A$2:$A$200,0)-1,1)
```

but it only pulls from 1oz, and I need it to pull from however many ounces are needed. So if I needed it to pull the correct amount if I upped it to 2oz, then this formula wouldn't work.

(The -1,1 is because this formula pulls from a drop down list and it was always one row off)

Thank you!

Comment: Change D3:I3 to actual numbers and use a custom number format of `General\o\z`. e.g. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVG8m.png). Once that is done you can simplify your formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do that:

[image]

```
PriceTbl refers to: A3:I6 
Spirit refers to: B11 
Size refers to: B12
```

The formula is:

```
=VLOOKUP(Spirit,PriceTbl,MATCH(Size,INDEX(PriceTbl,1,0),0),FALSE)
```

`Match` determines which column to use

`Index` with a column value of `0` will return the entire first row as an array.

You will need to adjust your references to suit.

Note that, as you have in your example, the `oz` quantities are expressed as text strings and not as numbers.